# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Please have a look at the packages I have in my Xamarin.Forms project.

[image]

Suddenly, without any changes, I started to get the shown error. I got similar issue one time and fixed by updating the packages. But right now, all the packages are up-to-date.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have re-added reference for `Mono.Android.dll` from the location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v11.0`.

When I moved the location of the project, I guess the reference was broken.

Comment: I have same problem with mac

Comment: @Vijay Can you try my resolution. Now it works fine for me.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you look in the .csproj file for Mono.Android.dll you will fine a path with multiple ../../ in the path. I do not k now why this type of path is used but for me it really messed up everything. This is an issue every time you change where the project/solution resides.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rauf I had to correct the reference of the dll file. To do that, go to `.csproj` and find a line that says

```
<Reference Include="Mono.Android">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v10.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
```

For me at least, it was pointing to old VS2019 folder so I had to just edit the path

Answer (score -1):

..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v12.0\Mono.Android.dll

Change the part "HintPath" or check it is the correct path
I have this Property in my .csproj file, so I changed this path for the version of Visual Studio 2022, I brought my app from Visual Studio 2019, this is the reason why it did not work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).