# Visual Studio 2022 cannot find Android.App.ActivityManager in Mono.Android.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, dll, xamarin.android

I have recently upgraded my visual studio from 2019 to 2022 and I'm now having an error in my project, specifically, Android Studio cannot find Android.App.ActivityManager in the Mono.Android.dll installed in my Xamarin Forms App. Can anyone help me to solve this?

The errors from Visual Studio are:

The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'RunningAppProcessInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'Android' does not contain a definition for 'App'

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Visual Studio?

Comment: @SophartPhun, yes I have, but nothing has changed

Comment: I see. How about cleaning the solution and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes, did that as well. But I can't seem to have a solution

Comment: There is a similar case which may give you some ideas.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372578/errorcs0246the-type-or-namespace-name-android-could-not-be-found-are-you-mi)