# Xamarin Forms project created with Visual Studio 2019 is missing Mono.Android when opened in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, xamarin, build

Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Using Android is missing wherever it has been omitted.

I created this Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2019 but when I open it using Visual Studio 2022, it give this error

Comment: Did you forget to install the correct VS workloads?

Comment: I opened the same repository

Comment: you did not mention the error you are facing

Comment: 1. You can try to re-added reference for Mono.Android.dll from the location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v11.0`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67375491 2. It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [Report a problem with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)